# Does Locust provide a sub-path in url?

Tags: user-interface, path, locust

I am using kubernetes with istio and trying to deploy locust.
The issue which I am facing is that Locust does not have any subpath like abc.com/locust/*
This causes locust to create paths at abc.com/
And this does not work because I have default routes in case of '/'
It would be very helpful if the Locust resources are mapped behind a sub path like /locust/
Also, if this sub path is made configurable(for ex var_sub_path=locust123) then it would be perfect to deploy it for different teams also.
Thanks